# Cocompact Discrete Subgroups

Tags: differential-geometry, topological-groups, lattices-in-lie-groups

I am reading a notes on homogeneous dynamics and I encountered the following statement 
"any discrete subgroup $\Gamma\subset G$ such that $G/\Gamma$ is compact is a lattice of $G$". How to prove this claim?

Comment: By lattice you mean $G/\Gamma$ has a finite $G$-invariant Borel measure?

Comment: yes that is what i mean

Comment: Are you assuming $\Delta_G |_\Gamma=\Delta_\Gamma$?

Comment: I don’t think it is assumed in the book

Comment: What book?${ }$

Comment: Sorry I mean notes. It’s in the proposition 1.2.4 https://www.math.u-bordeaux.fr/~jquint/publications/RiggaCourse.pdf. (

Comment: I know how to prove the assertion when $\Gamma$ has a fundamental domain, but I don't know what happens in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

It's proved in Proposition B.2.2 in the [Bekka-Harpe-Valette book](https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/bachir.bekka/KazhdanTotal.pdf).